# PDO update ERROR while trying to update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

am trying to update user info, it works fine but

there are 5 column when i update only single column other four column value becomes empty (it override previous value)

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$fullname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname']);
$dob = htmlspecialchars($_POST['dob']);
$gend = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gend']);
$address = htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']);
$intrested = htmlspecialchars($_POST['intrested']);

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET fullname = :fullname, 
            dob = :dob, 
            gend = :gend,  
            address = :address,  
            intrested = :intrested  
            WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':dob', $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// use PARAM_STR although a number  
    $stmt->bindParam(':gend', $gend, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':intrested', $intrested, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


header('Location: profile.php');
?>
```

here is my code to update user info

When i update only one column other four column values should be same

can some one help me

Comment: so you need to update multiple column , and not override with empty values

Comment: I would prefer to bind only those parameters you want to update and change the update statement accordingly

Comment: use `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` statement to check if you're getting values in `$_POST` as expected.

Comment: @OleK if i update `fullname` and leave other input empty code should update only full name

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this maybe?

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET ";
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(empty($v)) continue;
    $sql .= "$k = :$k";

    $stmt->bindParam(':$k', $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$sql .= " WHERE username = :username";
```

Of course it needs more things to do (check if it's PDO::PARAM_STR for example).

Also a "mapping" for proper columns is recommended

**UPDATE**

(the below will not work as is - just giving you ideas)

An advanced solution might be to extend the PDO class with an *update method**

```
    public function update($table, $pairs = array(), $condition = "", $mode = null){
            if($mode == null)
                $mode = self::STMT_UPDATE;
            $sql = $this->buildStatement($table, $pairs, $mode);

            $params = array();
            $sql.= $condition;

            if($mode == self::STMT_UPDATE)
                $params = array_merge($pairs, $params);

            $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
            return $stmt->execute($params);
    }

    /**
     * INTERNAL method to build up all statements
     * 
     * @param string $table
     * @param array $pairs
     * @param number $statementType
     * @throws Exception
     * @return string
     */
    private function buildStatement($table, $pairs = array(), $statementType = 0){
            if(!is_array($pairs) && ($statementType & ~9)) throw new \Exception("buildStatement failed: parameter \$pairs is invalid");
            if(empty($pairs) && ($statementType & ~9)) throw new \Exception("buildStatement failed: parameter \$pairs is empty");

            $sql = "";
            switch ($statementType) {
                    default:
                    case self::STMT_SELECT:
                            $sql.= "SELECT ";
                            if(count($pairs) > 0)
                                    $sql.= implode(', ', $pairs);
                            else
                                    $sql.= '*';

                            $sql.= ' FROM '.$table;
                            break;
                    case self::STMT_INSERT:
                            $tableFields = array_keys($pairs);
                            $sql.= 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (`' . implode('`, `', $tableFields) . '`) VALUES (:' . implode(', :', $tableFields) . ')';

                            break;
                    case self::STMT_UPDATE:
                            $setQuery = array();
                            foreach ($pairs as $field => &$value){
                                $setQuery[] = '`' . $field . '` = :' . $field;
                            }
                            $sql.= 'UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $setQuery);
                            break;
                    case self::STMT_UPDATEADV:
                            foreach ($pairs as $field => &$value){
                                $setQuery[] = '`' . $field . '` = ' . $value;
                            }
                            $sql.= 'UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $setQuery);
                            break;
                    case self::STMT_DELETE:
                            $sql.= 'DELETE FROM ' . $table;
                            break;
            }

            return $sql;
    }
```